# How to read Word .doc files?

Tags: file-format, word-processing

How can we read Microsoft Word (`.doc`) files in a Linux system? It doesn't support `.doc` files. I tried

> `strings filename.doc | less`

but it gives ugly output. Any other option?

I would prefer a GUI based tool.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want a graphical solution, then you might be able to open them with [Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/) or [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/).

There's also [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/)

> Antiword is a free MS Word reader for Linux and RISC OS. There are
> ports to FreeBSD, BeOS, OS/2, Mac OS X, Amiga, VMS, NetWare, Plan9,
> EPOC, Zaurus PDA, MorphOS, Tru64/OSF, Minix, Solaris and DOS. Antiword
> converts the binary files from Word 2, 6, 7, 97, 2000, 2002 and 2003
> to plain text and to PostScript.

[catdoc](http://freshmeat.net/projects/catdoc/) -

> Catdoc is a MS Word file decoding tool that doesn't attempt to analyze
> file formatting (it just extracts readable text), but is able to
> handle all versions of Word and convert character encodings.

And a couple of other options mentioned [here](https://www.linux.com/news/viewing-word-files-command-line/) (linux.com).

Answer (score 9):

I'd add [docx2txt](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/) to the list - mainly for reading the cursed new `.docx` format (*Late$t $tandard*<sup>tm</sup>).

Answer (score 5):

I've found [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) to be one of the more adept at handling word files on Linux. The formatting isn't always as close as [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) (the big boy on the block and your main bet) but what does come through usually ends up in a cleaner more usable format.

Answer (score 2):

I usually encounter these when I am online.  If you are using Firefox or one of it's stepchildren,  I recommend the [Docs Online Viewer plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/docs-online-viewer/) for this.  A little eyeball icon appears next to any type of document it can handle.  Just click on the eyeball to view.

It handles: "PDF, DOC, DOCX, XLS, PPT, RTF, ODT, ODS, ODP, CSV and many other formats"

There is a Chrome version, but I have not used it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the free [MS Word Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4) running with [wine](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wine).